# NameError: global name 'name' is not defined when using multiple files and Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to show the filepath of an accessed file in an 'Entry' box in Tkinter. Because of the requirements of this task I have to define all the functions in one file, and all the Tkinter fields in another and import the functions into the Tkinter file.

I tried putting all the code in a single file to see if that was causing any issues, and it worked fine. The problem is the task requires that I use seperate .py files.

```
def open_file():
    filePath = askopenfilename()

    with open(filePath, 'rU') as anotherFile:
        inputString = anotherFile.read()

    filePathEntry.delete(0, END)
    filePathEntry.insert(0, filePath)
```

And in the other file:

```
from AT3_Functions_v2 import *
main = Tk()
main.geometry("600x400")
openfile = Button(main, text="Open Scoresheet", command=open_file).grid(row=0, column=0)
filePathEntry = Entry(main)
filePathEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)
mainloop()
```

When I put both segments of code in a single file it works flawlessly, however when I seperate it again it gives me the error:

```
NameError: global name 'filePathEntry' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you place all your code in one single file then your **open_file** function can find **filePathEntry** variable. But when you split the code in two script then **open_file** can not find **filePathEntry** because it is in different file.

To solve this then you need to pass an argument in your **open_file** function using **lambda** function then place pass **filePathEntry** variable from another file. I have done for you.

***script_one.py***

```
from tkinter import *
from script_two to import *

main = Tk()
main.geometry("600x400")
filePathEntry = Entry(main)
filePathEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)
openfile = Button(main, text="Open Scoresheet", command=lambda: (open_file(filePathEntry))).grid(row=0, column=0)   # Passing arugument to open_file function which is in script_two.py
mainloop()
```

**script_two.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog


def open_file(entry_box):   # Passing argument to access filePathEntry variable from script_one.py
    filePath = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    with open(filePath, 'rU') as anotherFile:
        inputString = anotherFile.read()

    entry_box.delete(0, END)
    entry_box.insert(0, filePath)
```